# How can I construct another primary key in a table of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key, mybatis

Here's the table columns:

```
id | A | detail
```

`id` itself is primary key auto increment. `A` is the field that I want it to be **unique**.

I don't want to do `select id from table where A = "XXX"` every time to check whether there is a same A in the table already.

What I want:

1. When there is a same A in the table, don't insert, just return the id for me.
2. When there is not a same A in the table, insert it, after which return the id for me.

I'm using `mybatis`, and the amount of records is very large, **10 million** or so, so I need the solution to be effective enough.

Could anyone give me an idea how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: 10 million is not large. Just create an index and use explain to check that your queries are using it

Comment: I don't know how to use `explain`, could I just add something to enforce it to use the `index`? Plz give me some code snippet. Thanks!@EdHeal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to guarantee that column A is unique is to declare it unique. Only the dbms can guarantee uniqueness.

1. When there is a same A in the table, don't insert, just return the id for me.
2. When there is not a same A in the table, insert it, after which return the id for me.

MySQL supports an [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement. It's documented behavior is

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inserts or updates a row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Use with caution--the linked documentation cites bug reports.

I'm sure mybatis provides an easy way to get the value of last_insert_id().

Comment: According to LAST_INSERT_ID() documentation it will not return id value if INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will follow update path, so this unfortunately does't resolve issue #1

Comment: Then you should report that as a documentation bug. And test to see which of the two different documented behaviors is right.

Comment: FYI: using `insert ... on duplicate key update id = last_insert_id()` can retrieve the original id. @RomanKonoval

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE (A);
```

That should make A unique.

Comment: Wouldn't it affect the speed of `insert` when the amount of records is about 10 million?

Comment: I don't know that, but I guess it may take a bit longer since it has to check whether there is another A in the table.

Comment: Yes it would effect the speed - needs another index. But then again you might get efficiency savings on insertion and deletion